# Jquery mobile dialogbox without changing page

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I have to display dynamic popups in phonegap appliction.I made the popups dynamic using Jquery mobile and javascript but popup have white background throughout the application.
Please help me to get this in correct form. 
    Html code:

```
<div id="popupMsgPage" data-role="popup" data-close-btn="right" data-theme="c" data-overlay-theme="c">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" >
            <h1 id="popup-head">Delete Page?</h1>
        </div>
        <div role="main" class="ui-content">
            <h3 class="ui-title" id="popup-title">Are you sure you want to delete this page?</h3>
            <p id="popup-content">This action cannot be undone.</p>
            <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-rel-count="1" data-role="button" >Continue</a>
        </div>
```

Jquery Code:

```
 function show(head, title, msg) {
        debugger;
        head = head ? head : "";
        title = title ? title : "";
        msg = msg ? msg : "";
        jPages["popupMsg"].find("#popup-head").html(head);
        jPages["popupMsg"].find("#popup-title").html(title);
        jPages["popupMsg"].find("#popup-content").html(msg);
        $.mobile.changePage("#popupMsgPage", {
            role: "dialog"

        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mixing up the popup widget and dialog pages.  If you don't want to change page, use the popup widget like this:

```
function show(head, title, msg) {
    head = head ? head : "";
    title = title ? title : "";
    msg = msg ? msg : "";
    $("#popupMsgPage").find("#popup-head").html(head);
    $("#popupMsgPage").find("#popup-title").html(title);
    $("#popupMsgPage").find("#popup-content").html(msg);

    $("#popupMsgPage").popup("open");
}
```

> Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Ld5cy3bc/)**

Comment: I got an error like "cannot call methods on popup prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'".Then I called this-"$("#popupMsgPage").popup();" before "$("#popupMsgPage").popup("open");"and it is working.
Thanks.

Comment: @Anurag_Panday, if you use the page events like pagecreate, then the popup will already be initialized. See the $(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1",... part of the fiddle.

Comment: What others options I can use in place of pagecreate.Popup Ui gets changed when i used above methods.no header and other thins are added in popup dialog

Comment: @Anurag_Panday, I don't understand what you are asking. Can you edit the fiddle to reproduce your issue?

Comment: I got it,it depends more on the jquery mobile version and jquery.

Comment: With a single page model application (multiple HTML pages, each per page), is there a way to put the popMsgPage into an independent HTML page and made it generic by having able to call it from a different page?

Comment: @huggie, if it is a simple message popup, why not just create it in script, add to dom, initialize it, and then show it when needed? Check for its existence first so you only create it once.